# Display related columns from database in two cascading dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

i work on an asp page with c# code, the page should display universities names from database in the first dropDown then display all college names in the second dropDown according to the selected university name, the problem is in the second dropDown which dispaly all colleges for all universities not just the selected one, this is my code and i use oracle database i have one table that contain two coloumns uni name and colg name both of them are primary keys.
i hope someone can help me

```
private void BindDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, string query, string text,string defaultText)


{        

string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString))
    {
        using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            ddl.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddl.DataTextField = text;

            ddl.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(defaultText, "0"));
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string query = "select UniName from Colg";
        BindDropDownList(ddlUniversities, query, "UniName", "Please Select University");
        ddlColleges.Enabled = false;

        ddlColleges.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select College", "0"));

    }
}

protected void University_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlColleges.Enabled = false;

    ddlColleges.Items.Clear();

    ddlColleges.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select College", "0"));

    string uniName = ddlUniversities.SelectedItem.Value;

    string query = string.Format("select ColgNamef from Colg where UniName = uniName");

        BindDropDownList(ddlColleges, query, "ColgNamef", "Please Select College");
        ddlColleges.Enabled = true;

}
protected void College_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string query = string.Format("select ColgNamef from Colg where UniName = '{0}'",uniName);
```

Comment: i tried this before and an oracle error occur but when i see your answer i recognize that i miss the single quote of {0}, thank you so much